# Pass Environment Variable to angular.json File. (Angular7)

Tags: angular, environment-variables, build-process

I am trying to use an environment variable in my angular.json file.  I suspect this isn't possible, but thought I would see if anyone knew how.  I am using it to point to a signalr file generated by the server (issue being when in dev vs. staging it's a different baseUrl).
So...
angular.json

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ab-inbev-web2": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],

            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "http://site-dev.com/signalr/hubs"
and when on staging
              "http://site-stage.com/signalr/hubs"
            ]
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  baseUrlWithSlash: 'http://site-prod.com/',
  logoffWarningTimeoutSeconds: 600,
  production: true,
  searchDelimiters: /[,;\n]+/
};

environment-local.ts
  export const environment = {
      baseUrlWithSlash: 'http://site-dev.com/',
      logoffWarningTimeoutSeconds: 600,
      production: true,
      searchDelimiters: /[,;\n]+/
    };
```

ect...

I am trying to avoid hard coding it and trying to have it work while running local.  I thought maybe there is a way to sniff the location in the angular.json file and do an if statement.

Comment: @user184994  is a way to sniff the location in the angular.json file and do an if statement to append to the script location?

Comment: When you do a build, you pass the environment, such as `ng build --prod` for example. You can use environments I guess? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: Since when JS has access to env variables??:>

Comment: @Antoniossss It doesn't, but Angular has an `environments.ts` file, which may provide the functionality that OP is after.

Comment: idk, he asked about ENV . Obviously environments is what he is looking for.

Comment: Right I have environments files setup as in the wiki all that works.  I am trying to augment the actual script location in the angular.json - based on the environment or location that angular.json exist (local, site-dev, etc.)

Comment: are you looking for something like `ng serve --configuration=<env>`?

Comment: I am thinking more of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular... just found.

Comment: Found this too -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741457/angular2-load-script-conditionally-using-angular-cli Closing question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741457/angular2-load-script-conditionally-using-angular-cli

Comment: @RooksStrife might be worth reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51490031/1990451 ; not answering this question but could give some hints still

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741457/angular2-load-script-conditionally-using-angular-cli I not different then using environment file.....

Comment: Use dynamic script loading instead of add it into your CLI config.
Example of service to allow dynamic script loading : https://github.com/gilsdav/angular-lazyload-script-service